# Recover data from external disk with SMART failure

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a WD My Passport Ultra external hard drive which failed after my laptop restarted in the middle of a file transfer. Since then I'm unable to open the files in the hard drive. Even though I can browse the files and view the file names and sizes, whenever I try to open a file I get an error message `device not ready`.

I scanned the disk with WD Drive Utilities and the SMART status check fails, which apparently means that the disk is corrupted. I tried to recover the files with Recuva which failed because the recovery software couldn't read the dist. Is there any way to recover the files in that disk or it's completely written off?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds pretty unfortunate, @Vasilis! :( I'm afraid that if there's any important data on the WD My passport, you might want to consider contacting [a profession data recovery company](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=cE6K4v) for assistance. They would be your best bet on getting any of the files back since the external HDD also fails the SMART tests from the DLG tool. In the future, always make sure you keep your files on at least 2 different storage devices to avoid such unpleasant situations! Backups mean that you have duplicates of the files. :(

As a last resort, you could also try using a [Ubuntu Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) to see if you will be able to gain access to the files. However, nobody can say for sure how successful that attempt would be.

I'd also recommend [checking the WD My Passport warranty status](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=9Tv2PZ). If it's still covered, you should be able to send an RMA request to our [Customer Support](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=ednv2U) and get a replacement.

Best of luck! Hope I was helpful.